# Why the query still run when the condition didn't meet?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, rows-affected

I got the following testing SQL statement that link to the database. I do not have any record in the database that matches 900 but it returns the results = 1 instead of 0. Can I know what is the reason for this?

```
$query = "update mytable set verify = 'yes' where number ='900'";

$result = $conn->query($query);

if (!$result){
    $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>0)) . "]";        
}
else {
    $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>1)) . "]";        
}

echo $json_out;
```

Comment: Because you have put `json_encode(array("result"=>1))`

Comment: No record  in the database is changed despite it running the statement. I just need it to be result = 0 when it does not meet condition so that I can show error message at the front end

Comment: Ya, I know that. But the query executed fine & there will be a `$result`, you can use `print_r($result)` to see if there is any & confirm.

Comment: @Sinto what are you expecting to see from `print_r($result))`?

Comment: I was trying to say that the `$result` will be `true` even if there is no affected rows in DB as per above code. So that he can confirm that by himself by using `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

Answer (score 2):

You get the 1 result because you are not checking for affected rows.  The query has no errors, so you get the 1 outcome.

For your outcome to be accurate you need to check zero versus non-zero affected rows.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Untested suggestion:

```
echo json_encode(['result' => (int)($conn->query("UPDATE mytable SET verify = 'yes' WHERE number = '900'") && $conn->affected_rows)]);
```

In other words, if the query returns a non-false result and the affected rows result is non-zero, then the whole condition evaluates as `true`. If you cast `true` as an integer, you get 1; `false` becomes 0.

Comment: They're probably going to ask you how to do that.

Comment: That makes sense. I can't remember if `mysqli_error($con)` would throw an error though. It's been a while since I last did a test for a case like that *lol*